# WKWebView не открывает ссылку

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Через WKWebView перехожу на https://ya.ru/, там делаю поиск, например "Википедия", после чего пытаюсь открыть первую же ссылку, но ничего не происходит.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class WebViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewOutlet: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.webViewOutlet.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://ya.ru/")!))
        self.webViewOutlet.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить протокол, указать его делегата и добавить метод.
Я комментариями отметил места, где добавил все это в ваш код.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {  // Здесь протокол WKUIDelegate
  
  @IBOutlet weak var webViewOutlet: WKWebView!
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.webViewOutlet?.uiDelegate = self // Делегат
    
    self.webViewOutlet.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://ya.ru/")!))
    self.webViewOutlet.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
  }
  
  // И этот метод
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
      webView.load(navigationAction.request)
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!